# javascript pattern replacement using backreference is not working

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, backreference

```
string.replace(/([\t])/g,"\\$1")
```

is **working** fine where

```
string.replace(/([\n])/g,"\\$1")
```

is **not working**!!!

any idea please???

N.B.

```
string.replace(/\n/g,"\\\n")
```

is also working fine

Comment: Looks like multiline support problem - tried in different browsers?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the input? What is the expected output?

Comment: i am getting an error message "unterminated string literal" when i am trying to access the values of a textarea field having newline characters. i want to escape the newline characters from the input.

Comment: If you're getting "unterminated string literal", then the problem is in the code, not the value. There's literally a mismatched set of quotes or an extra slash somewhere.

Comment: which line gives you the error? The line to retrieve the textarea's value? Or the line that tries to do the replace. I tested your Regex, and it's functioning fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/J9wtH/ And, what do you mean by escaping? Your first regex is not gonna work. You're simply adding a slash before the linebreak, like converting "whatever (newline)" to "whatever \\(newline)", it's not really removing the newline - In your "N.B.", that regex seems to be doing what you meant to do.

Comment: @Max, you might be right. I am rechecking my script. As it is very complex script something might ignore my eye.

Answer (score 0):

Use a script to [capture the enter keypress event](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/support-tabs-in-textareas/) and replace it with '\' prior to submission.